# How to solve unknown error when registering ios app in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-console

I have a Firebase project with all my clients' apps. The service I provide is that of push notifications. I am trying to register an iOS application and all I can get is the following error message:

> "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."

[image: "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."]

I have double checked the bundle ID, and the rest of the data even though is optional, but have the same result. I have read in some chats I should log out and back again and it would be created, nope. Tried also in an incognito window and didn't work either.

As this is an "Unknown error" I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Thank's a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: There's not a lot anyone here can do about this. The first thing I'd always do is check the JavaScript console of your browser for more details and run in an incognito window with all browser extensions disabled. If that doesn't provide a solution, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with Firebase technical team and they have solved my problem!

I had exceeded the registered IDs I could have in a single project and, therefore, I couldn't add a new one.

However, this problem is not solved just eliminating the app in Firebase, but entering in your Google Cloud service > APIs and Services > Configuration, and there you can manage the auto-generated iOS IDs.

I hope this solve some of your problems too!